# How to \input{} files with Unicode names?

Tags: texstudio, unicode, input-encodings

I work in Linux with the latest TeX Live. The system encoding is UTF-8. It is also the default editor encoding in my TeXstudio 2.12.8.

I have figures in files like `σ_1_μ_02_per_5.tikz`, and I included them using `\input{}`.

Now, the most interesting part: it had worked fine (even without `inputenc` etc), then it just stopped. I have not change a single line in my files. Now I get

```
Package inputenc Error: 
Unicode character σ (U+3C3)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
...σ_1_μ_02_per_5.tikz
```

I have tried:

- using `babel`
- `inputenc` with `utf8`, `utf8x`, `latin1`
- `fontenc` with different parameters
- opening and saving in UTF-8 in other editors

And in this case I get:

```
Undefined control sequence. ...μ_02_per_5.tikz}
Missing $ inserted. ...μ_02_per_5.tikz}
Double subscript. ...μ_02_per_5.tikz}
Undefined control sequence. ...μ_02_per_5.tikz}
```

How to fix this?

---

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \input{1.tex}
    \input{σ.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try compiling with `xelatex`. as a rule of thumb, it's ill advised to use such characters in file names, as they might end up on other systems which can not deal with them.

Comment: The simplest way is use a UTF-8 native engine such as `lualatex` or `xelatex`.  As @naphaneal notes, such characters can cause problems. It's also advisable to not use spaces or underscores in filenames. As a workaround for `pdflatex` you can use `\input{\detokenize{σ.tex}}`

Comment: btw, the `.tex` extension is not required for `\input`.

Comment: It is not only Greek letters, try with `\input{é}` (or the equivalent `\input{é.tex}`.) This was already case with TL2017 and earlier and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` or even `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. And the `\detokenize` workaround was applied already then in those old times.

Comment: The disadvantage of XeTeX etc options is that I have to review packages, e.g. `babel` -> `polyglossia`, isn't it?

Comment: @homocomputeris use the `\detokenize` workaround and don't modify your set-up.

Comment: @homocomputeris There are some differences, mainly with fonts, so instead of loading `fontenc` you would load `fontspec` (or nothing); `inputenc` is not needed. As for `polyglossia` vs. `babel`, no, for most European languages, `babel` works well with UTF-8 engines, so there's no need to switch to polyglossia.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Such file names have never worked if you are using `inputenc` to allow the use of the characters in input to typeset text. It would previously have worked if you were using the old default raw 8-bit default input as the bytes just passed through and were then interpreted as UTF-8 by the filesystem

With the current LaTeX release inputenc UTF-8 handling is assumed by default.

As Alan commented above you can use

```
\input{\detokenize{σ.tex}}
```

to allow the filenames even after UTF-8 inputenc processing has been loaded.

Hopefully in a future release the `\detokenize` won't be necessary, but it will always work.

Comment: Although I don't completely understand the 'byte passing' part, this is the answer, as are the comments above. Is it possible to renew the `input` command to work with `detokenize`?

Comment: @homocomputeris sure but I wouldn't as while I can be fairly sure the above form will work in future if you redefine it to apply detokenize automatically it may not, and several other packages will break because `\input{\myfile}`  will try to input `\myfile.tex` not whatever name the comand `\myfile` expands to. You can however safely do `\newcommand\myinput[1]{\input{\detokenize{#1}}` then `\myinputσ.tex}`

Answer (score 0):

I use `make4ht` with a source file that input another source which filename contains some utf-8 character:

```
\input{scénario1}
```

If I only use the XeLaTeX compiler, it works. But if I use it through the make4ht command,

```
make4ht -c ../make4ht.cfg --xetex -d html main.tex "Gin-percent"
```

then it fails.

The error is :

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   special 
l.20 \input{scénario1}
                      
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Use of ??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> ???  
                ! LaTeX Error: special invalid in file name. Lost: {t4ht@+&{...
l.20 \input{scénario1}
                      
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   special
```

Using the solution above from David Carlisle (@david-carlisle), it works:

```
\input{\detokenize{scénario1}}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)


make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3l

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!